# Sum of ActiveCell.Offset Values

Tags: excel, vba

having issue with the below coding I'm putting in for a VBA macro.

Simply trying to sum 2 cells

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = SUM(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 4).Value):(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of adding is not the best way but just to answer your question, the below code should work

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 4).Address & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Address))
```

Comment: why is this not the best way ?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/1651993 . May be your requirements are different but usually I avoid using Select, Activecell etc.